# Using external functions within Pyomo constraints

Tags: python, pyomo

I need to use an external python function to create a constraint in a pyomo model, but I do not trust that it works as it should. E.g. if I have the following external function

```
# External function
def total_cost(length, flow):
    return length * floww * 1000
```

and then I want to call it when creating a pyomo model object but 'length' and 'flow' values are variables within my model, will that work as it should?
Anyone has any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your example should work fine for most cases. There are three exceptions you want to watch out for (but these apply to normal constraint rules as well):

1. Don't explicitly take the `value` of a variable when building a constraint expression because the variable will be replaced with a constant numeric value in the expression tree (and not sent to the solver)
2. Don't write conditionals (if-statements) that depend on the value of a variable
3. Only use Pyomo provided intrinsic math functions (sin, cos, exp, etc.) when writing constraints

I also recommend calling `pprint` on your constraint after it has been constructed to verify that the constraint expression is what you expect. If the constraint is too long/messy then you could `print` the subexpressions returned by your functions and verify that you are getting Pyomo expression objects rather than constant numeric values.

Comment: Thank you so much Bethany. I will make a note of these.

In my case, my python function has a log10 expression. I import the pyomo log10 function & use it when calling the function for the pyomo constraint, and then the normal numpy for every other evaluation. My question stems from the fact that on solving the model, the result variable value (evaluated using that function) is different from when I pass the function dependents manually.

Any clues as it why? Thought it was because I was calling an external function & pyomo may not have been using the variable correctly. pprint works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting different values, it sounds like your variables are being replaced by constants or they are set to different values when you're doing the comparison. Are you using an `AbstractModel` or `ConcreteModel`? Could you include a minimal example that recreates what you're seeing?

Comment: I am using a ConcreteModel.

I will try to create a minimal example with reproducible errors and get back to you.

Comment: Just following this up Bethany. First apologies for the delay. 
Good news though. Found the problem!!
I was using BARON solver. Turns out BARON does not process log10 only natural log. So when I write out a constraint with Pyomo's log10, it is processed properly by pyomo but the .bar sent to BARON uses the natural log. BARON's manual says to use the natural log always but with a multiplier to convert to log10 at the constraint level. I did this and both model results and manually post-processed values are the same! Thanks again for your pointers Bethany, will try to raise in GitHub as well.